# Execute bat file on client machine through Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, batch-file, asp.net-core-mvc

We have a web page which lists our own custom zipped files(stored at cloud).
We want those files to be unzipped the moment user downloads it.

For unzipping process we have provided a console app to user which will be stored at a known location(say C:/ProgramFiles/Company/UnZip.exe) on client machine.

We will also be saving a batch file on the client machine to execute that console app with arguments to unzip the file.

We are aware this can be done on IE using ActiveXObject, but we need a cross browser solution.

Any help/alternative will be appreciated.

Comment: Nope, not possible. Think of all the security issues it would open up, if a page could automatically download a file and run something on the host OS!

Comment: @phuzi, is there any alternative or anything by hook or by crook,  thanks btw.

Comment: As far I know, it might not be possible in browser, however, did you able to run this in any browser so far?

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron, No, and for the best, we now have shifted to a more robust solution. Thanks, btw

Answer (score -1):

```
try {
    Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
    intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE"); //this line is optional, you can pass extra information to the app with this code
    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
} catch (Exception e) {
    Uri marketUri = Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.google.zxing.client.android");
    Intent marketIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,marketUri);
    startActivity(marketIntent);
}
```

There are a variety of approaches that can be taken to solve the same problem How To Start A New Application From Another Application? Examples. The remaining options will be discussed further down.

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MakeKey.class);
startActivity(i);
finish();
```

As we have seen, the issue with the How To Start A New Application From Another Application? Examples variable was resolved by making use of a variety of distinct instances.

Step 1 − Create a new project in Android Studio, go to File ⇒ New Project and fill all required details to create a new project. Step 2 − Add the following code to res/layout/activity_main. xml.30-Jul-2019

Step 2 − Add the following code to res/layout/activity_main. xml.30-Jul-2019

Sorry for copy paste, there are some ideas how to do it in android studio.

Comment: This answer is irrelevant to this question as 1. Its Android. 2. I have to run a app on interaction with a webpage, not an application.